# Bullets disappear with CSS3 columns

Tags: css, html-lists

The bullets on my list items disappear when I convert them to columns using CSS3. Any ideas why or suggestions on how to correct it?

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/gduDm/1/

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
    margin-top: 1em;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I think the bullets are there, but they're being rendered to the left of the viewing area.  Try:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

Comment: Yes, this is just because you are using jsFiddle, which doesn't show bullets properly.  I wish they'd update their CSS on there.

Comment: It actually didn't work in my site code either. The list-style-position worked perfectly though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Absolutely Andrew - glad that I could help!

Comment: That is a good work around but now the 2nd line of text [doesn't line up](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v357/BFTrick/list-position-inside-bullets.png) with the first line.

Comment: @BFTrick Try adding left padding.

Comment: thanks, stupid bullets would disappear when I added overflow to the <ul>

Comment: `text-indent: -1em; padding-left: 1em;` fixed the alignment for me

Comment: `margin-left:1em` makes the bullets appear without messing with the text indentation.

Comment: Should your solution be set to `ul` or `li`? I am assuming `ul`.

Answer (score 20):

Adding both `padding-left` and a negative `text-indent` to the list elements seems to produce the desired result:

```
ul li {
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
ul {
    list-style: inside disc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gduDm/4/

Alternatively, add a `margin-left` to the list element (instead of the list) and use `outside` bullets:

```
ul li {
    margin-left: 1em;
}
ul {
    list-style: outside disc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/gduDm/9/

Comment: This (the 2nd solution proposed) is the superior solution IMO because the text alignment remains intact when list items overflow onto multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `margin-left:1em` makes the bullets appear without messing with the text indentation.

Answer (score 2):

After trying the first answer here, I was having issues with my list items spilling onto a second row and not lining up.  Using `column-gap` I was able to move the second column over and see the bullets.

Source: http://karlikdesign.com/how-to-split-a-list-into-two-columns-with-pure-css/

```
    <!– CSS CODE –>
    .two-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to say that this saved my sanity after hours of investigating the cause of my custom list images (a pdf icon) were disappearing for the second column.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other solutions are pretty good, but all the ones I tried caused various side effects for me.  I made some small tweaks and tried to get it as close to perfect as possible.

```css
ul {
  column-count:2;
}

ul.solution {
  margin-left:-0.6em;
  margin-right:0.6em;
}

ul.solution > * {
  margin-left:0.6em;
  margin-right:-0.6em;
}
```

```html
Experimental Group
<ul class="solution">
 <li>
  This solution is pretty similar to the others.
 </li>
 <li>
  It does not require you to put the bullets inside, so you can keep your left edge clean if you want. 
 </li>
 <li>
  This fixed it for me in IE11 while also not impacting the appearance on Chromium, so I didn't have to do any browser filtering.
 </li>
</ul>
Control Group
<ul>
 <li>
  This solution is pretty similar to the others.
 </li>
 <li>
  It does not require you to put the bullets inside, so you can keep your left edge clean if you want. 
 </li>
 <li>
  This fixed it for me in IE11 while also not impacting the appearance on Chromium, so I didn't have to do any browser filtering.
 </li>
</ul>
```