# CSS columns make my LI bullets disappear

Tags: css

How do I get my *outside* list bullets back?

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/s9FVT/

```
.two-column-list {
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: outside disc;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
}
.two-column-list li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

When I use CSS columns on an unordered list with `outside disc` bullets, my bullets disappear, regardless of the padding on the list element.

[I can get them back by using `inside disc`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10855627/901048), but then my long lines wrap under the bullets, which I also want to avoid.

Adding a negative `text-indent` to the `<li>` elements also doesn't work; it just crops off the first few letters.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome. Firefox seems unaffected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding both `padding-left` and a negative `text-indent` to the list elements, while making the list itself `list-style: inside disc`, seems to solve the problem:

```
.two-column-list {
    padding: 0 0.4em;
    list-style: inside disc;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;
}
.two-column-list li {
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -1em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/s9FVT/6/

Comment: It seems that simply making the list style position to `inside` brings back the bullets. The rest is just for positioning.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `list-style-position: inside` on the `ul` element:

```
.two-column-list {
    /* all the other stuff */
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s9FVT/3/) or on the `li` elements:

```
.two-column-list li {
    /* all the other stuff */
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

([JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s9FVT/4/)).

Or you can simply assign a `margin-left` to the `li` elements:

```
.two-column-list li {
    /* all the other stuff */
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s9FVT/5/)).

Comment: I noted that in my original question. Additional styles on the list elements are needed to keep the text from wrapping under the bullets.

Comment: Then increase the `margin`.

Comment: Post the CSS code, please?

Comment: The only code I changed is in the answer, but if you wish...